# POPLIB poplib.error_proto: b'-ERR [AUTH] Username and password not accepted.'

Tags: python, poplib

The following code works with another gmail account of mine, but fails with the account im now using, I've already set up POP3 for both accounts!

```
import email, poplib
from email.header import decode_header
_MAXLINE = 2048

login = 'genericmail@gmail.com'
password = 'genericpass'
pop_server = 'pop.gmail.com'
pop_port = '995'

mail_box = poplib.POP3_SSL(pop_server, pop_port)
mail_box.user(login)
mail_box.pass_(password)
```

The error:

```
raise error_proto(resp)
poplib.error_proto: b'-ERR [AUTH] Username and password not accepted.'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to enable ["Access for less secure apps"](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) in your Google Account.

Comment: This setting is no longer available.

Comment: It is replaced by "App Password". Make sure to have two-factor-authentication enabled and go here to generate one: https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

Comment: To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.

Comment: @harlekintiger The setting you are looking for is not available for your account.